# Find projection-datum type for coords

Tags: dictionary, gis

I try to find a way to get the projection type of the following coords.

I need to convert these coords in WGS84 latitude longitude format. I have only 1 hint: these coords are located in Florida-USA (Broward County)

```
<XCoordinate>9082520</XCoordinate>
<YCoordinate>6563620</YCoordinate>
```

Thanks

Comment: Where did you get these coordinates from?

Comment: In what context did you find these numbers; could they have been relative to a map you were looking at (in other words - they were describing where on the map the point was)? It looks like a grid reference... but it's not clear what the grid is. Do you have a website or something where you found this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your data are in "SPC" (State Plane Coordinate) system. This is often used for "local" coordinates - it makes calculations for such things as distances and routes much easier. If that is the case, and the county in question is Broward (which is zone 0901), then there is still some guessing to do... because one can use "US feet", "International feet", or meters in this system.

If you go to http://www.earthpoint.us/Convert.aspx you can enter your coordinates in the "Position" box. Depending on what you choose you will get different answers. I suggest you try to see which makes sense (if you suspect the coordinates are for a post office and you land in a lake you probably are using the wrong number):

```
0901 908252.0ftE 656362.0ftN gives 26°08'14.5036", -080°13'53.8483"
```

That puts you pretty much on top of a bus stop - which I guess is what the Hastus system might be giving you...

[image]

Comment: do you know a C++ or C# tools to do  the conversion?

Comment: I don't - until today I didn't even know what SPC coordinates were... But there appears to be useful code and links [here](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=64&f=786&t=188996)